# Remember on which desktop window belongs

Tags: linux, kde, kde-plasma-5

How to setup that a window (e.g. SMPlayer) is automatically shown after its start on all desktops?

PS: I know there is `kstart`, but I would prefer less hacky solution, one that works out of box with associated files and preferably can be activated via GUI for any application after installation/setup of this feature is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Kubuntu 16.04.1 (KDE Plasma 5.5).

1. Click on the window icon (usually on the upper left corner of the window)
2. Go to "More Actions" -> "Special Application Settings"
3. Choose the "Size and Position" tab
4. Set "Desktop" to "Apply initially", "All Desktops".

Comment: Great! Didn't know about that whole menu. Works nicely, thank you :).